# Custom workflow activity shows up but can't be selected?

Tags: 2010, workflow, visual-studio, workflow-activity

I have created a custom workflow activity and successfully deployed it.  The issue I am running into is that when I try to select it when creating a workflow using SharePoint designer, nothing happens.  It does not get added to the workflow, there are no errors, just nothing.  I have been watching the ULS also and nothing is showing up in there either.

Does anyone have any idea why this would happen?  Suggestions for where I should start looking?

If there are any parts of the project that will help with this question, let me know and I will post them up.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The most common issues are:

- Make sure the authorizedType entry is in your web.config (for testing you can manually add it or [add it using code](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/32318/modify-web-config-programatically-to-add-a-workflow-authorized-type))
- If this is a new iteration of an existing DLL, you may have to [clear your cache](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sharepointdesigner/archive/2007/03/27/tip-clearing-the-spd-workflow-assembly-cache.aspx) on the machine where you are using SharePoint designer.
- Make sure your .actions file is correct.

You might also want to check out [Muhimbi's answer](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/a/16020/2070) on [Custom activity created and appearing in Actions list in SPD, but cannot select it](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/16016/custom-activity-created-and-appearing-in-actions-list-in-spd-but-cannot-select).

Comment: One of my Web Applications was missing the authorizedType. Thanks.